# How to Modify a list of Image URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been scraping sites and retrieving image information regarding them.

However, I need to have a `http://` or `http://www.` or `subdomain` of the site to the image src if it doesn't contain it.

Is there a quick function in rails that works on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try looking at Ruby itself and its [string documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html), for example there is [start_with?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001179) which checks if string starts with the input, you can use something like this:

```
domain = "http://domain.com/"
image = "image.jpg"

unless image.start_with?(domain)
  domain << image.url
end
```

You should be able to come up with a method to iterate over all your scraped images and update them.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use Ruby's URI module in the event that string comparison isn't catching everything.

```
require 'uri'
```

Just the image:

```
# let image.url = "image.jpg"

uri = URI.parse(image.url)

uri.scheme
#=> nil
uri.host 
#=> nil
```

Without the http scheme:

```
# let image.url = "domain.com/image.jpg"

uri = URI.parse(image.url)

uri.scheme
#=> "http"
uri.host 
#=> nil
```

With everything:

```
# let image.url = "http://domain.com/image.jpg"

uri = URI.parse(image.url)

uri.scheme
#=> "http"
uri.host 
#=> "domain.com"
```

By checking `uri.host` and `uri.scheme`, you can add add either as needed.

Comment: nice one. I'll consider that.

Comment: Nice one indeed, I have good experience with [addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) but this one should work just as well.